# Exclude excerpt from wordpress wp_query

Tags: php, wordpress

Hellow everyone!
I am showing blog of posts in additional wp template and everything works fine, but I've made some kind of gallery from it, and I don't need to show anything except gallery and title.

Inside posts I have this:

```
[gallery ids="1618,...,1634"]
<h2>...</h2>
<p>...</p>
text without format, etc.
```

As you can see, I am using a gallery shortcode. I need it to be shown, but all other content to be excluded from the loop.

Really appreciate your help in this question...

My template code:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template name: Блог
 */
$current_page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'paged'          => $current_page,
    'cat'            => 8
);
query_posts( $args );

$wp_query->is_archive = true;
$wp_query->is_home = false;

while(have_posts()): the_post();
    ?>
    <div class="foto_posts">
        <?php the_content()  ?>
      <?php  echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" class="foto_title" target="_blank">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';?>
        </div>
    <?php
endwhile;

if(function_exists('page_navi_slider')) page_navi_slider();
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove "<?php the_content()  ?>"?

Comment: Sure. Gallery stops showing up, cause it is in the content...

Answer (score 0):

try to replace  `<?php the_content()  ?>` to  `<?php the_title()  ?>`

Comment: Then I just get title except gallery. I guess I need some complicated rules, which gonna get only images, galleries and video (yea in some posts I got video too), and exclude everything else...

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to show gallery shortcode try this

**replace**

```
<?php the_content()  ?>
```

**to**

```
$pattern = get_shortcode_regex();
preg_match('/'.$pattern.'/s', $post->post_content, $matches);
if (is_array($matches) && $matches[2] == 'gallery') {
   $shortcode = $matches[0];
   echo do_shortcode($shortcode);
}
```

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately... Moreover videos posts in iframe

Comment: maybe this simple approach can help . 
move/copy `[gallery]` shortcode to post excerpt than replace `<?php the_content()  ?>` to `<?php echo do_shortcode(the_excerpt) ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this for getting galleries and videos use the `get_post_meta_key()`

```
<?php get_post_meta($post_id,'key_name',1);?>
```

If it returns an array then traverse that array to get the images link and video links

```
add_shortcode('gallery', 'gallery_shortcode_fancybox');
function gallery_shortcode_fancybox($attr) {

    $attachment_ids = explode(',',$attr['ids']);

    $args = array(
        'post__in' => $attachment_ids,
        //'cat'            => 8 if category needs to be shown pass it in shortcode , same as ids
    );
    $gallery_posts  = query_posts( $args );
    foreach ($gallery_posts as $key => $value) {
        //do the stuff here
        echo '<h2>'. $value->post_title;'</h2>';
        $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($value->ID);
        echo '<p><img src="'.$feat_image.'" ></p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: If I not mistake, gallery_shortcode_fancybox - is the Fancybox plugin. If it is so, i don't use this one. I have Cherry Framework installed and "gallery" is it's plugin.

Comment: gallery_shortcode_fancybox is the name of callback function you can change it to something else